# Point stabliziers of primitive permutation groups are maximal primitive subgroups

Tags: group-theory, permutations

While reading Kurzweil & Stellmacher's Theory of Finite Groups, chapter 6.6, Primitive subgroups are defined:

a group $M$ is primitive if for every If  for every non-trivial $N \unlhd M  \Rightarrow  M = N_G(N)$.

Then, it is mentioned that it is clear that every Point stablizer of a Primtive permutation is a primitive subgroup. I do understand why it is maximal because the action itself is primitive, but why would the stabilizer $G_\alpha$ contain no normal subgroup of $G$?

Thanks

Comment: What is $N_G(N)$?

Comment: @flawr The normalizer of $N$ in $G$. $\{x \in G|x^{-1}Nx =N\} $

Comment: Because a ormal subgroup of a transitive group $G$ contained in $G_\alpha$ would fix every point and therefore be trivial.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you!